# Android - Manually write()ing to AudioTrack, no appropriate MediaRecorder.AudioSource

Tags: android, audio, record

I see that MediaRecorder allows you to record from the Microphone, or a phone call.

I'm using write() on an AudioTrack to produce sounds out of basic frequencies. Multiple AudioTracks actually.

I would have thought that there would be a MediaRecorder.AudioSource setting that captured whatever sounds the system was sending to the speakers.

I tried DEFAULT but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no loop back audio source for recording sounds generated by the device, just from external audio sources.